# can someone please tell me why foreachloop is not taking i as 1 which is a variable that is used to check whether it is in exist in the array or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

```
    k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i=1
k.forEach((element,i) => {
    if(element===i){
        console.log("TRUE")
    }else{
        console.log("False")
    }
});
```

output: False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False

*i was excepting true but it is giving me false what to do?
guys i know array index starts from 0 , i want to check whether the element present or exist in the array or not using foreach not forloop, thank you each and everyone for trying to help me out, i'm just a begineer if you guys think this is silly question i'm sorry in advance and thank you all*

Comment: Why to expect a true? The array indexing starts from zero.

Comment: `i` in this code of `forEach` becomes the index.

Comment: Because `i` is the index of the element. You are comparing `1===0`, `2===1`, `3===2` etc. Since arrays are 0-indexed (and not 1-indexed) it can never be true.

Comment: dont pass i into the loop and done

Comment: Also if you're looking for a way to know if `k` includes `i` you can write `k.includes(i)`

Comment: @Indratej You say "I was expecting true but it is giving me false" - what is this script supposed to do? Is it supposed to echo "TRUE" only once (because `k` includes `1`), or are you trying to check the values of `k` against their index, in which case "TRUE" should be output 8 times? You have `.forEach((element,i)` which is overwriting `i=1` in the loop. So you either need to change that var to something like `find = 1` and then `if(element === find) {`, or change `forEach((element,i)` to `forEach((element)` to not use an internal index variable.

Comment: @JeremyThille my friend , i want to try with foreach not forloop or while or any built in methods, is it possible using foreach?

Comment: `forEach` loop is impractical for finding a single value from an array, as you can't break the loop.

Comment: So, you want to know if `k` includes `i`, but you do NOT want to write `k.includes(i)`, you WANT to write a brand new in-house `forEach` loop that is much slower and will iterate the full array and can't be interrupted? Be my guest

Comment: if youre trying to check if the i exists then just use `indexOf`, or alternatively use Js `Set()`s, and use the built in method

Comment: Using a foreach loop for this is EXTREMELY inefficient and impractical. Just run a Google search for Js array methods, and then, if you find nothing, revert to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to ask a question, and what questions should be asked here.

Comment: @AlphaHowl I don't think OP cares about it being inefficient. I have pointed out `k.includes(i)` multiple times, but they just don't care, they absolutely want a `forEach` loop and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables called `i`.  Which one do you think is being used in your comparison?

Take a look at [the documentation for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).  The second parameter to the callback function is the index of the array.  And since array indexes start at `0` and your array values start at `1`, the index of any element in your array will never equal that element itself.

If you want to use the `i` variable that you defined outside of the function, don't shadow it with the second parameter to the function:

```js
k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i=1
k.forEach((element) => {
    if(element===i){
        console.log("TRUE")
    }else{
        console.log("False")
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah or `k.includes(i)`

Comment: @JeremyThille: Indeed.  Though the resulting output would of course be different.  (More useful in my opinion, but different.)  The OP could also just use a normal loop, but indicated specifically that he wants to do this with `.forEach()`, so this is really just pointing out the error in the implementation.

Comment: As an aside for future readers, at this time `.includes()` requires a polyfill for IE.  The older approach of using `.indexOf()` and checking for a non-negative result is more universal.  If you need to support IE.  And if you do, you have my sympathies.

Answer (score 0):

`i` will be the index of your current `element`.

```js
k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
k.forEach((element,i) => {
    if(element===(i+1)){
        console.log("TRUE")
    }else{
        console.log("False")
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the i++, and remove the i in k.forEach(element,i)

```js
k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i=1
k.forEach((element) => {
    if(element===i){
        console.log("TRUE")
    }else{
        console.log("False")
    }
    i++;
});
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for updating your question, in that case try this:

```js
k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i=1
k.forEach((element) => {
  if(element===i){
      console.log("TRUE")
  }else{
      console.log("False")
  }
});
```

Because you call the i in the foreach loop, the i will change and is never equal to i, check and try it below

```js
k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i=1
k.forEach((element,i) => {
console.log('i: ' + i);
console.log('element: ' + element);
});
```

*Note, please try to formulate your question more clear in the future*

Comment: What does this achieve exactly? OP wants to know if `k` contains `i`

Comment: I dont really understand the question, but to achieve the same results as the above snippet, you can leave out `i=1` and do `k.forEach((element,i)`, then `if(element===(i+1))`, as this is a more tidy way of doing it.